# How can I create a stored procedure or trigger to update 2 columns in a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, view, triggers

I am trying to create a stored procedure to update 2 columns from a table in SQL Server. I have 2 tables `products` and `order details`.

Every time a product is sold, I want to update the `product_quantity` column, which means `product_quantity - quantity` (product on hand minus the quantity that is ordered). The `product_quantity` attribute should not go below 0.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I tried to build a view

```
drop view if exists v_products
go

create view v_products 
as
    select 
        product_name, product_quantity, product_status, 
        quantity, p.product_id
    from
        products p
    inner join 
        order_details od on p.product_id = od.product_id
```

and then tried to create a procedure based on the view.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS p_products_product_quantity
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE p_products_product_quantity
    @product_quantity INT,
    @sold_quantity INT,
    @product_status VARCHAR(50),
    @product_id INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE v_products
    SET product_status = @product_status,
        quantity = @sold_quantity,
        product_quantity = @product_quantity,
        product_id = @product_id
        -- ,product_quantity = @product_quantity - @sold_quantity
    WHERE @product_quantity - @sold_quantity = 0
END
```

I am expecting for example if I have

```
product_quantity 23
```

and quantity of the next order (sold quantity) is 23.

I want the `product_quantity` to change to 0 and `product_status` to 'not available'.

Comment: I would not be using an updateable view for this, a trigger is almost certainly more appropriate.

Comment: @P.Salmon How can I create the trigger?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

I see someone already mentioned that you can use a trigger for this so im going to give another alternative if you dont want to go down that route. You can just update both tables within the scope of your insert into the order table eg :
--Inserts order here

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO order_detail
    VALUES (@unit_price, @size, @quantity, @discount, GETDATE(), 
    @productid, 
    @orderid, @paymentid) --Im assuming you have already inserted into your order table in a different caller or same stored procedure
    UPDATE product
    SET product_quantity = (product_quantity - @quantity)

    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK;
END CATCH
```

In your stored procedure you will wrap it around a transaction so if all inserts and updates were successful it will commit that transaction to the database and if a single operation fails on the stored procedure then we rollback (all previous operations will be rolledback to ensure we dont create orphaned rows)

Hope this helps! :)